# Tool to migrate from DB2 to MySQL

Tags: mysql, db2

There was a MySQL migration toolkit can migrate from DB2 to MySQL, but the MySQL site says it's not available any more. However, I can't find a substitute for that in MySQL workbench CE.

Where is the substitute or alternative solution?

---

**I just need a tool that's free and easy to use to help me migrate a db2 schema to mysql.**

Comment: Similar question at the link below, their discussion/links might help: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1797/migration-from-db2-to-mysql

Answer (score 7):

You can Try Talend application... infact it is a Dataware housing Tool and a data Migration tool as well. It is supports DB2, Mysql, Postgres, Oracle, PeopleSoft and a lot more. U can Find It here `http://www.talend.com/products-data-integration/talend-open-studio.php` and Ofcourse Its an Open Source tool...

Comment: Interesting find! CaiNiaoCoder was probably looking for something completely automatic, but I doubt that exists. Tool like Talend wold surely help.

Comment: I downloaded it, but how to use it to migrate db2 to mysql? it's confusing

Answer (score 1):

have you looked at http://www.ispirer.com/products/db2-to-mysql-migration ?

They have express version which is free but limited, but it might be sufficient for your use, anyways I don't see a reason why not invest some money since moving from DB2 to mysql will save you tones of money on support on the long run!

Answer (score 0):

You can use various ETL applications like Talend, SSIS and Informatica to migrate data from DB2 to MySQL.